# How to setup CORS with Angular, SpringBoot and Nginx proxy

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy

I recently moved my SpringBoot to a newer version of boot (2.x -> 3.1.2) and now I'm getting nothing but headaches from the CORS configuration.

[www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) points (AWS Route53) to a CloudFront distribution.
data.domain.com points to an ec2 instance, on that instance there is an nginx server that should proxy requests through to the SpringBoot application.

I just don't seem to be able to get my CORS setup quite right since the upgrade.

In the browser console the only info I get for a 403 request is "Invalid CORS request". So something in my CORS config appears to be blocking that request.

I am happy it's CORS config rejecting requests rather than role/authentication.

I am happy to accept I don't understand this CORS stuff as well as I should, so any advice appreciated!

**Spring config:**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity( 
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        // https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        var allowedCorsMethods = List.of("POST","PUT","GET", "PATCH", "OPTIONS");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(allowedCorsMethods);
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        if (Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch("development"::equalsIgnoreCase)) {
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        } 
        // relying on nginx proxy to set allowed origin in prod
        // if I add here I get errors in browser about it being set twice (add header here and in proxy)

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(withDefaults()) 

           // snip role / url matching stuff ....
                
                 .addFilterBefore(
                        jwtTokenFilter,
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
                ).build();
}
```

**Nginx proxy config:**

```nginx
server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name data.example.com;

   ssl_certificate              /etc/ssl/certs/data.example.com.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key          /etc/ssl/certs/data.example.com.key;
   ssl_protocols                TLSv1 TLSv1.2;

   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://www.example.com always;
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range always;
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH always;

   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  location / {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://www.example.com always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range always;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH always;
            add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;
            add_header Content-Type 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            return 204;
        }

        proxy_http_version  1.1;

        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://www.example.com;
        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range;
        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH;

        proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
  }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    return      403;
}
```

**Relevant bits of build.gradle:**

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
    id 'java'
}
sourceCompatibility = 17

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api-parent:2.3.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:6.2.4.Final'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
}
```

Comment: Why configure CORS support in Spring if you're handling it in NGINX already?

Comment: Guess I assumed the java server would need to be configured to support or it would reject everything proxied through

Comment: Nope, CORS is enabled server-side but the rules only apply on the client

Comment: Well I've turned off cors in Java server, don't get same errors. I'll have to go do some reading to get a better understanding of CORS I guess.

@Phil If you're bothered about useless SO points, feel free to create an answer and I'll accept it